# Stack overflow parallel updating one RT index

Tags: multithreading, sphinx

Is it possible to update ***one*** `Real-time Sphinx index` in `parallel`?

To clarify, I have one RT index, named e.g. RT1. To update RT1, I want to have two or even more updaters.

For instance, if I have 100 files in the queue, I want to add 2 files in parallel to the index. Is Sphinx capable of multi-threading or is Sphinx not thread-safe?

The main question is, will Sphinx corrupt itself when multiple files are being added to the same index at the same time? I wasn't able to find the answer in the documentation.

*Good to keep in mind, I `multithread` my `script` which is adding files to the Sphinx RT-index. Therefore, multiple files will be added **at the same time (in parallel)** to one index.*

**Version**:

```
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
```

***Config:***

```
index_name
{
  type            = rt
  path            = /mnt/data001/index_name
  rt_field        = FileName
  rt_field        = FileExtension
  rt_field        = FileContent
  rt_field        = FileTags
  rt_attr_uint    = FileReference
  rt_attr_uint    = FileSize
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModified
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedYear
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedMonth
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedDay
  rt_attr_string  = FileContent
  rt_mem_limit    = 1024M
  charset_table   = A..Z, a..z, 0..9, U+E1, U+E9, U+FA
  ondisk_attrs    = pool
}

searchd
{
  listen                = 9306:mysql41
  log                   = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  read_timeout          = 5
  max_children          = 30
  pid_file              = /var/run/searchd.pid
  max_packet_size       = 128M
  binlog_path           = /mnt/data001
}
```

Important to note that the string can only consist of A..Z, a..z, 0..9, U+E1, U+E9 and U+FA. (I have verified this)

**Test:**
for the test I used a C++ application on Ubuntu communicating with Sphinx through the MySQL connectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified this issue and be warned! Updating the index in parallel is not possible! My index corrupted itself **partially** (both the index and daemon didn't crash). You will not see this issue at a first glance. I have verified this by inserting and checking the inserted value (by directly selecting it after insertion) and the returned value didn't always match the inserted value as outlined below.

As an example for clarification. I inserted `test` but I got back `t^463t` from the select (directly after the insertion was performed).

For this test I have inserted `1.000.000` documents spread over a `two-threaded` application whereof `43.372` documents had this issue outlined above. This of course is dependent of the exact rate of parallel inserted documents, but ***Sphinx doesn't seem to be thread safe***. (assumed is that even more documents will get corrupted when using more threads to insert documents in parallel)

Sometimes I also noticed that words from multiple documents where concatenated (those documents where inserted at the exact same moment).

Comment: Wow. I'll appreciate if you let me know how exactly to reproduce this. I'll be glad to reproduce it in Manticore Search and we'll then fix it promptly.

Comment: As stated above, I made a two-threaded application inserting documents in parallel in Sphinx. Sphinx seems to work with a memory range where the words of the documents are inserted through each other? You can verify this by inserting the documents and directly query back the content and compare the result with the inserted string of content (words). This will show the difference in content inserted and returned by Sphinx (Sphinx mixes the words from the parallel inserted files, at least that is what it seems to do). If you want to have further contact to fix this issue, let me know

Comment: Since you didn't provide the exact way to reproduce the issue I made some assumptions (e.g. that you saw the problem in a string attribute), but couldn't reproduce the problem with Manticore Search. I've published my research here https://github.com/Ivinco/stress-tester/tree/test_rt_insert_with_docker

Comment: I'll appreciate if you provide the exact way how to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, I indeed use the string attribute (rt_attr_string). As stated above, when updating the index in multiple threads (I tested with only 2 threads), the inserted value get's corrupted for quite a lot of docs in a set of 1.000.000 documents as outlined above. I verified this by selecting the inserted value and immediately compare this value against the inserted value. This lead to many mismatches. These mismatches sometimes consisted of multiple words from files that where inserted quite closely to each other

Comment: Well, as I said I can't reproduce it now :( Let's think what can be different in our tests. Mine is fully opensourced on github and can be verified in just 3-4 commands on any server. Can you share more details about yours? What's the version of Sphinx? What are the documents etc.? Settings in the config file.

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, I have been able to reproduce the issue even in a single threaded test where I inserted 1.000.000 documents and 8 of those documents had the same problems as outlined above. I will add more config details to my original question

Comment: Thanks for the details. Can you also provide an example of one-two documents? I'll try to reproduce it on 2.2.9

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, is 2.2.9 the latest version anyway? I installed it via apt. How can I attach documents here, and what documents do you want? Just two random of the set?

Comment: No, 2.2.9 is quite old. Check on sphinx site for newer versions.

Comment: I've updated https://github.com/Ivinco/stress-tester/tree/test_rt_insert_with_dockerso it uses 2.2.9 apt package and your config and still can't reproduce the issue. Can the problem be in the C++ app?

Comment: I don’t think so. I log the values I’m inserting (which are good) and check them against the queried value. This value is different for some files and the problem therefor seems to be in Sphinx?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, may be of importance for your tests: I insert the words encrypted. (Words all consist of the charset defined in my config). Could this perhaps break Sphinx in some cases?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen Do you expect Sphinx to fix this issue when I update to the latest version?

Comment: You can try Sphinx v3 or Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx with many things changed). What do you mean by words encrypted? It would be really helpful to get a fully reproducible case. Can you provide Dockerfile or vm archive or just a full detailed instruction?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, I have enabled my logging again. When I have a document that has the same problem, I will let you know. Perhaps you can send me a private message so we can communicate easier for the tests to be made to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen, I have another example of the problem where I have logged the inserted value and directly queried back the value from Sphinx. They differ. The file however is 6.5MB. How can I share this file with you?

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen ?

Comment: if you can reproduce it with Manticore Search feel free to file an issue on https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticore and provide the file there or contact me at http://slack.manticoresearch.com We'll be glad to look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, it won't corrupt your index and shouldn't crash the daemon.
Related answer with some tests made - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961820/591867

Comment: See my answer. I have made some tests and I concluded that Sphinx can't handle the situation correctly. At first, it seems to work well, but when you investigate it further, words in the index aren't always correct. The index is still (partially) usable and the daemon won't crash, but returned results aren't always correct.